# Linq - How to group by multiple fields and count the records by one of the fields

Tags: c#, linq

I want to have just the same result as the following query:

```
select SITECODE, COUNT(SITECODE), DATEPART(MONTH, LOG_DATE) 
from dbo.LOG_VEHICLE_LOOKUP GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, LOG_DATE), SITECODE
```

I'm using Entity Framework as the ORM

My current linq looks like this:

```
        var model = from log in _repository.GetPostcodeLookupLogs()
                    group log by new { log.LOG_DATE.Month, log.SITECODE } into y
                    select new 
                        {
                            y.Key.SITECODE,
                            y.Key.Month,
                            Count = y.Count()
                        };
```

Comment: And what happens with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was thinking the correct way. I got confused because I wanted to use

```
_repository.GetVehicleLookupLogs()
```

instead of:

```
_repository.GetPostcodeLookupLogs()
```

Both tables had the same columns so I got some results but not the ones I expected